# Issue with summary() function in R

Tags: r

I am new to programming and trying to learn R using swirl.

In one of the exercises I was told to use the summary function on a dataset. However I encountered a discrepancy in the way the summary was printed:

[image]

Instead of summarizing the categorical variable values, it instead says something about length, class and mode.

I went around searching for why this might be happening to no avail, but I did manage to find what the output is supposed to look like:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using R version 4?

Comment: You will get the summary table for factors, but your variables are character.  This is likely due to a recent change in R, which no longer converts character columns to factors automatically in functions like `read.table`.

Comment: If you want to see the data as frequencies. Convert them(character, leave primary keys or other nominal data) into factors. Or if you don't want to that then use table on those columns(but beware do not use this command on columns like ids/ dates)

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, it's been a massive help!

I am using R version 4.

I understand why R interprets the column headers as strings now, how do I convert them to factors though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is due to the option *stringsAsFactors*, which is FALSE by default on R 4. Previously it was TRUE by default:

From R 4 [news](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.pdf): *"now uses a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE' default, and hence by default no longer converts strings to factors in calls to data.frame() and read.table()."*

---

A way to return to the previous behaviour with the same code is to run `options(stringsAsFactors=T)` before building dataframes. However, there is a warning saying this option will eventually be removed, as explained [here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html).

For your new code, you can use the *stringsAsFactors* parameter, for instance `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=T)`.

If you already have dataframes and you want to convert them, you could use this function to convert all character variables (you will have to adapt if only some variables need conversion):

```
to.factors <- function(df) {
  i <- sapply(df, is.character)
  df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.factor)
  df
}
```